# Bad argument to 'random'

Tags: lua, roblox

This is my code

```
while true do
    script.Parent.Position = Vector3.new((math.random(-41.994,15.471)),0.5,(math.random(129.514,69.442)))
    script.Parent.Color = Color3.new(math.random(0,255), math.random(0,255), math.random(0,255))
    wait(1)
end
```

The programming language I am using is Lua

When I try to use this code I am presented with this error:

```
"15:50:47.926 - Workspace.rock outer walls.Model.Rocks.Part0.Script:2: bad argument #2 to 'random' (interval is empty)"
```

The purpose of the code is to randomly teleport the part the script is in around but not to far away and at the same y axis.

Can somebody please give me some form of explanation

Ps. A while ago I made a rude post on this website because I was confused at how to do a lot of things and now I understand some stuff better so I would like to apologize for my idiocy ~Zeeen

Comment: I edited your post to fix the formatting and change the title. Your original title didn't provide enough information.

Answer (score 2):

In Lua, `math.random` can be called 3 ways:

- with no arguments
- with 1 integer argument
- with 2 integer arguments

It does not accept values like `-41.994` or `15.471` this is why you're getting the error.

If your change your values to `-41` or `15` you shouldn't see an error any more.

---

Lua 5.3 reference manual: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.random

> math.random ([m [, n]])
>
> When called without arguments, returns a pseudo-random float with uniform distribution in the range [0,1). When called with two integers m and n, math.random returns a pseudo-random integer with uniform distribution in the range [m, n]. (The value n-m cannot be negative and must fit in a Lua integer.) The call math.random(n) is equivalent to math.random(1,n).
>
> This function is an interface to the underling pseudo-random generator function provided by C.

Answer (score 1):

As Nifim's answer correctly points out, there are three ways to call `math.random` in Lua.

With no arguments, it returns a real number in the range 0.0 to 1.0.

With one or two integer arguments, it returns an integer.

None of these directly give you want you want, which **I presume** is a random real number in a specified range.

To do that, you'll need to call `math.random` with no arguments and then adjust the result.

For example, if you wanted a random number between 5.0 and 10.0, you could use

```
math.random() * 5.0 + 5.0
```

Consider writing your own wrapper function that takes two floating-point arguments and calls `math.random`.

```
function random_real(x, y)
    return x + math.random() * (y-x)
end
```